# What is the difference between these variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

A function in my program takes the variable `DAT` and when I try passing args through it fails. I am pretty sure `DAT` is a JSON and args is array. How would I change args to same variable type as `DAT`.

here is my code:

```
const args = message.content.match(/\b[^"]+\b|(?!")\S+/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase().slice(prefix.length);


if(command === 'hello'){
    message.channel.send("I only research leave me alone");
    let DAT = ['AAPL', 'PYPL', 'GOOG', 'A'];
    console.log("dat: " + DAT);
    console.log("args: " + args);
    console.log(DAT, args);
}
else if(command === 'research'){

    let DAT = ['AAPL', 'PYPL', 'GOOG', 'A'];
    stockdata.realtime({
        symbols: DAT,
        API_TOKEN: world_token
    })
    .then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        //console.log("symbol" + response.symbols_returned)

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("error");
    });

}
```

the result in console

```
PS C:\Users\gaming pc\bot_code\researchbot> node index.js
ready
dat: AAPL,PYPL,GOOG,A
args: 
[ 'AAPL', 'PYPL', 'GOOG', 'A' ] []
dat: AAPL,PYPL,GOOG,A
args:  AAPL PYPL GOOG A
[ 'AAPL', 'PYPL', 'GOOG', 'A' ] [ ' AAPL PYPL GOOG A' ]
```

Comment: `DAT` is not a JSON, since it is not a string, and only strings can be JSON. `DAT` is an array. Also, it would be great if you would explain the intended meaning of your regex.

Comment: _"`console.log("dat: " + DAT)`"_  **never** use string concatenation in the console if you want to see what an object actually looks like. Try `console.log('dat', DAT)` instead. Even better, use a debugger

Comment: that console debugging tip thank you really helped didn't even realize. And I updated the code. DAT is how the data should look like sending to api and args is what is grabbed from the command line. I want args to replace DATin the research command but as you can see the variables are different

Comment: I am using the hello command to debug variables so I am not constantly sending requests to api while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression will produce only a single match for your example, `["AAPL PYPL GOOG A"]`. This happens because your regex is non-greedy. Without knowing exactly what you meant, I won't try to fix your regex; but `/\S+/` is sufficient to solve the problem you presented here.

Answer (score 0):

I used an expression from my other bot so I just changed the expression

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```